# Label Binding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, label

I am trying to bind a label to an Object.Object.Property and I don't get it run.

Here is my code:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MyWindow" Height="1120" Width="800">
    <Grid Name="MyGrid">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40" Content="{Binding MyDataObject/AnotherSubObject/MyProperty}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the **Code**:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MySubObject MyDataObject { get; set; }

    public MyWindow(MySubObject object)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MyDataObject = object; // Contains MyDataObject.AnotherObject.MyProperty

        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And the code for **MySubObject** object looks like this:

```
    public class MySubObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    AnotherObject _AnotherObject;

    public MySubObject()
    {
        this._AnotherObject = new AnotherObject();
        this._AnotherObject.Property = "Some Value";
    }

    public AnotherObject AnotherObject
    {
        get { return _AnotherObject; }
        set { _AnotherObject = value; OnPropertyChanged("AnotherObject"); }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

I would be glad to get dome support for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`Dot(.)`** as binding property path separator not **`Forward slash(/)`**

```
<Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40"
       Content="{Binding MyDataObject.AnotherSubObject.MyProperty}"/>
```

Comment: Just a last question on this case: How do I concat two Properties? Eg <Label Content="{Binding MyProperty1 + MyProperty2}"/> ?

Comment: You have to use [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) for this. Pass both properties to the converter and return concat result from there. Also, please refrain from asking follow up questions here which are not relevant to the question. Post separate questions in such cases.